# Update a large ledger efficiently

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

As the title states, I have a large ledger with over a thousand unique entries. I created an excel file that had a comprehensive list of all the items and how much of each item I had. That was my database.

Then, on a separate sheet, I had shipment log. So every time I got some new item, I would write the name of the item I got. Then, on the Database table, I wrote a COUNTIF formula to search the Shipement log and thus automatically update my inventory.

Now, as you might imagine, with over 1000 items, and thus over 1000 COUNTIF formulas, every time I put one item in my shipment log, excel would stutter and the calculating process would significantly slow down my spreadsheet.

So, I'm asking, is there some method of improving my automatically updating spreadsheet? The most promising method is using a pivot table to count for me, but in the end, I don't know how to add the amount to my database without using a COUNTIF anyway. Is this kind of slow processing inevitable for large spreadsheets? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever tried PivotTable that helps to summarise the ledger first?

Comment: If you are repeating a formula across multiple cells with minor variations and good amount of overlap, you may want to consider using arrays. So you could select the entire range of the column where you need to enter the COUNTIF, press F2 to enter the formula in the first cell and after completing typing the formula, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. This way one single formula gets copied across the range

Comment: To make the job faster and better I would like to suggest you to use Excel VBA !

Comment: Kenneth L - How would summarizing the ledge help? I'm not entirely clear on what you mean. Even if I summarize it, don't I have to use a COUNTIF to sort the new shipments?

Bharat Anand - Would array formulas be quicker than having the same formula in each cell? I always thought that array formulas were clunky.

Rajesh S - Could you please elaborate on how VBA could help?